# Does Hadoop MapReduce run on each and ever machine?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I have Hadoop running on a grid of 50 machines, And I run a job of determining which are the most common words, can I specify that I only want to search in documents abc1.txt and abc2.txt? 
How does Hadoop know on which machines to look for this files, or will it try to find the files on each of the 50 machines?

Comment: dude, read about HDFS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should specify the path to files in HDFS as input for your MapReduce job. But the good thing - you don't need to know where actually these files are stored.

When you upload `abc1.txt` and `abc2.txt` to HDFS - distributed file system, Hadoop would store data blocks from this files on several machines in cluster called nodes (3 by default). If the files size is bigger that one machine can store - Hadoop would split files into several blocks and would store the every block on several nodes.

So the job doesn't need to know where the files are actually stored. Your job program would just identify files by URI like `hdfs://abc1.txt` and `hdfs://abc2.txt`.

Hadoop tries its best to run job (or part of job) at the same node where the data is stored.

When Hadoop will schedule your job it will take into account which nodes has the data for the job and what node is available at that time. Then it will schedule job to run on the node.

In case if each file fits to one node, the job would be scheduled to run at one node per file. So it won't be run on all 50 nodes of cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In hadoop, you put the files on hdfs and it copies the files in multiple locations, say 3 copies of each file which are located evenly.

For example, you have 50 files and each has 3 copies in hdfs(this number is determined while setting up hadoop). Let say `Machine1` has `abc1.txt, abc24.txt and abc47.txt` and M2 has  `abc11.txt, abc24.txt and abc27.txt` and others are similarly.

When you give abc_*i*.txt(i is 1 to 50) as input, for `abc24.txt` hadoop is going to give the job to either M1 or M2 or the other machine that has the file in order not to have any network data transfer. And all other files are going to be processed by the machine that has the file (there may be some exceptional case in which these rule fails). For better understanding read this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).